# How to dynamically specify the Class of an object in Java?

Tags: java, dynamic

I am currently making a 2D game in Java and trying to rework my loading system. The data is stored in an array of an abstract class and my goal is to find a clean solution for how to dynamically decide which subclass should be added/set.

At the moment the game chooses the subclass by going through a `switch` statement with cases that have the exact same code in them, apart from the class. Example:

```
//imagine BlockType1 and BlockType2 are sublasses of the abstract class Block
Block[][] array = new Block[1][1]; //simplifying here
switch(id){
case 0:
  array[0][0] = BlockType1(/*constructor over multiple lines*/);
  break;
case 1:
  array[0][0] = BlockType2(/*constructor with the exact same arguments as above*/);
  break;
//...
}
```

But that is ugly code and a waste of space. This is how I imagine the solution:

```
public void loadContent(){
  //...
  //note: the Datatype and function below are of course just made up, but
  //this is how I think it could work
  DatatypeThatStoresSubclasses subclass = chooseSubclassById(id);
  array[0][0] = new subclass(/*arguments from before, but only once!*/);
  //...
}

private DatatypeThatStoresSubclasses chooseSubclassById(int id){
  //again, this is just made up - I don't know if it would actually work this way
  if(id == 0)
    return BlockType1;
  if(id == 1)
    return BlockType2;
  //...
}
```

So I am basically looking for a datatype that stores classes in a way that they can be used like in the second example, but maybe that's again just my imagination and there a completly different approach.

Comment: What about `Class.forName(myClassName).newInstance()` ? where _myClassName_ would receive a String like "myPackage.BlockType1" ? If you have parameters to send to their constructors you might wish to use `invoke(...)` method instead of `newInstance()`.

Comment: @Marc That seems like it could be the way to go. As you already pointed out, ```newInstance()``` does not work and gives me an ```InstantiationException``` instead, but the ```invoke()``` sounds interesting. However, it does not seem to exist. At least replacing ```.newInstance()``` with it is not possible and I can not find any documentation on it. Could you explain what to do in more detail please?

Comment: what about a factory method ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern